# What security level is provided by pairing curves in Charm Crypto?

Tags: security, elliptic-curve, charm-crypto

I want to know what security level is provided by the type a and type d curves which are included in charm crypto library? For example, the type a curves SS512 and SS1024 have a prime field of 512 and 1024 bits respectively? Can anyone tell me what security is provided by them?

Comment: probably more appropriate for http://crypto.stackexchange.com

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b If I ask on crytpo Stackexchange they will say it is related to coding and must be asked on stackover flow.

Comment: Table A-1 in https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4730686/ gives some parameters and their associated security levels.  I am unfortunately not familiar with this particular primitive.  In the table, `q` seems to be the field order...so you'll have to find `k` and `r` for your curves of interest.

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b Thanks for sending this. I will read the article and hopefully find the answer to my question